# An application of Greens's theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

> Apply Green's theorem to prove that, if $V$ and $V'$ be solutions of Laplace's equation such that $V=V'$ at all points of the closed surface $S$, then $V=V'$ throughout the interior of $S$.

Attempt:

Clearly, $\nabla^2V=0=\nabla^2V'$. Let $U=V-V'$, then $\nabla^2 U=0$.
We know that $\nabla U=\frac{\partial U}{\partial \bar{n}}\bar{n}$.  One can write by Gauss's theory here for $U$ that

$$\iint_S U\frac{\partial U}{\partial \bar{n}}dS=\iiint_V|\nabla U|^2dV$$

I have no idea how to go further as I have to use Gree's th (not div th) and how to understand about the conclusion  "at all points of the closed surface S", and "throughout the interior of S".

Although, I know the 2nd identity of Greens as
$$\iint_S (V\frac{\partial V}{\partial \bar{n}}-V'\frac{\partial V'}{\partial \bar{n}})dS=\iiint_V (V\nabla^2 V -V' \nabla^2 V')dV=0$$ (as $\nabla^2V=0=\nabla^2V'$).

Comment: Left integral$\iint_S U\frac{\partial U}{\partial \bar{n}}dS=  0$, as $U=0$ on $S$.

Comment: @NikitaEvseev The theorem I have applied is the Divergence th, here I have to apply Green th. Please help.

Comment: I suppose there is no Green theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) for $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @NikitaEvseev I don't understand, somewhere I have read that divergence theorem is sometimes called Green's theorem in space. If it is true, then still I am confused about the solution of my problem.

Comment: Green's Theorem $$\iiint_V u \Delta v dV = - \iiint_V \nabla u \cdot \nabla v  \; dV + \iint_S u \frac{\partial v}{ \partial n} dS $$ just replace the u and v with your function U, and use the condition that U satisfies the laplace equation on the boundary

Comment: @Dan Then how to use the theorem to solve my problem.

Comment: The moment you make the required substitution you obtain $$\iiint_V U \Delta U dV = - \iiint_V |\nabla U|^2 \; dV + \iint_S U \frac{\partial U}{ \partial n} dS $$

Comment: @Dan I understand your point. Please suggest me the further steps.

Comment: The surface integral is zero because in the laplace equation (especially dirichlet problem), we choose either the surface directional derivative to be zero or the function to be zero on the boundary

Comment: Hopefully the answer helped, if so consider accepting the answer, if not let me know how it didn't help understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Green's identity

$$\iiint_V u \Delta v dV = - \iiint_V \nabla u \cdot \nabla v  \; dV + \iint_S u \frac{\partial v}{ \partial n} dS $$

We define the new function $U = V- V'$ and replace both u, and v in the above

$$\iiint_V U \Delta U dV = - \iiint_V \nabla U \cdot \nabla U   \; dV + \iint_S U \frac{\partial U}{ \partial n} dS $$

Which simplifies to

$$\iiint_V U \Delta U dV = - \iiint_V |\nabla U|^2 \; dV + \iint_S U \frac{\partial U}{ \partial n} dS $$

The left hand integral is identically zero since we have that $\Delta U = 0$. Next you have to get rid of the surface integral. You have to make the assumption that since U satisfies the laplace equation, either require that $U=0$, or $\nabla U \cdot n = 0$ on the boundary. This means the surface integral is also zero. After that you have $$\iiint_V |\nabla U|^2 \; dV = 0 $$ Since V is arbitrary the integrand is identically zero $$ \Rightarrow \nabla U = 0$$ Which means that it is a constant, in the dirichlet problem we can choose this constant to be $0$ hence $$U = 0 \rightarrow V - V' = 0$$